# steps for deploying infopath form to sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I'm very new to Infopath, Sharepoint etc. I'm looking for step-by-step flow for deploying infopath form to sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying an InfoPath form to SharePoint means publishing. Just search for "Publishing InfoPath form to SharePoint". You will find a lot of articles.

**Edit:**
There are 3 ways to publish an InfoPath form; to a form library, as a Content type or as an administrator approved form.
I don't know your requirement but I believe the first approach will be enough for you. Have a look at this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uz3QbQuZYtI

Comment: yes :) actually I'm very new to it, am looking for the step-by-step proc to follow.